/bin/sh: docker: command not found when running a script from Python, but works in terminal
I'm trying to run Docker commands from a Python script using the subprocess module. However, I keep getting the error /bin/sh: docker: command not found. When I run the same command in the terminal, it works fine.
When I specify the full path
call('/usr/bin/docker version', shell=True)

it gives me /bin/sh: line 1: /usr/bin/docker: No such file or directory. Confirmed it by running
call('cd /usr/bin/ && ls', shell=True)

and there's really no docker executable there (from terminal with the same environment, it's all fine).
I also tried to explicitly set the PATH variable, but it also gave no results. User permissions from both the python script and terminal are the same.
What could be causing this discrepancy?
I'm using:
Arch Linux
Docker version 26.1.3
Python 3.12.3


What does type docker show in the terminal?

@Barmar docker is /usr/bin/docker

Are you running python in a venv?

@Barmar Yes, I'm in a conda environment.

Sounds like you don't have docker installed in that environment.

@Barmar when I use "conda activate my_env && docker --version" in terminal it works fine. It's not enough?

"When I run the same command in the terminal, it works fine." - exactly what commands do you run in the terminal, and what results do you get?

What happens if you try call(['/bin/sh', '-c', '"/usr/bin/docker version"']), manually doing the shell=True work? How about if you try call(['/bin/sh', '-c', '"type docker"']), to ask what that shell thinks docker is? Or, for that matter, call("type docker", shell=True)?

@KarlKnechtel I use "docker run ...", it's a script for file conversion, and it works as intended

@KarlKnechtel all these commands give docker not found basically. specifically
"/bin/sh: line 1: /usr/bin/docker: No such file or directory"
/bin/sh: line 1: type: docker: not found

I realized that it's some problem with VSCode. I barely use it, so I guess I forgot to configure something or I don't know. Jun run it separately in a terminal and magically the script worked.

VS Code can run a Docker image for software it starts. Make sure you turn off "devcontainer" support if you don't want this.
